# ASP.NET Web.config question

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

The server is IIS7.

Is there a way to disable web.config files in subfolders?

I am asking because, I have a folder on the web server that is for uploads. When someone uploads files, a new folder is created for the user's session and the files they upload go in the folder.

So the path to uploads would be like this:
~/uploads/3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301/somefile.txt

In the ~/uploads/ directory there is a web.config file that removes all http handlers except the static file handler and adds a wildcard mime type. So every file that a user uploads will only ever be served statically.

If a user uploads a web.config file, I want to disallow any of the settings in that file from being applied.

How can I do this?

## EDIT

Could I just make the upload folder an application that is a member of an application pool configured to run in Classic mode instead of Integrated Pipeline mode? That way it wouldn't even care about a web.config file.

## EDIT 2

Is there another type of webserver I could install for serving all files statically? I could just access the files through a different port. Is there some software that I can be sure wont run any scripts and is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have a different angle on this...

What if your uploads folder was not part of the website and instead part of the file system?  This way ASP.NET is not processing requests to the folder and thus web.config wouldn't be loaded by the ASP.NET runtime.

You'd have to give your app pool's account read/write access to the file system where these files are stored, but I think it better fits what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: But, I need to serve the files in the folder. I have thought about not having ASP.net serve requests (see my edit)

Comment: You'd have to add the ability to your app to grab the file from the file system and stream it to the user.  You *could* copy the file from the file system to a "staging" area for the user, but then you open yourself up to the same injection-style attacks that you had in the first place.

Comment: I have thought about that, too. But I kind of just wanted IIS to do it.

Comment: The problem with letting IIS do it is that you could be held hostage to any number of injection attacks, whether that be ASP.NET or classic ASP or (insert executing framework) unless I'm misunderstanding your edit.

Comment: How could code be executed if there are no HTTP Handlers? Every request will be mapped to the static file handler.

Comment: It looks like this is the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

I simply wouldn't allow them to upload a file with that name.  In fact, I normally wouldn't trust any filename that the user gave me... makes a great candidate for an injection-style attack.

Comment: +1 for re-naming files.  If you want to "remember" the original file name, store it somewhere else.

Comment: I have thought of that. That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it could be done in code.

If the folders always exist, you could pre-populate with a web.config with no (significant) content and an ACL to ensure it cannot be overwritten, but looking at the path it I suspect you create the upload folders dynamically which means this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to tell IIS not to use a web.config (but I could be wrong).  Personally, I would add a check to my save code and rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check the filename first to prevent the user from uploading a file named web.config?  You're probably going to want to check for other things too before allowing the upload - files that are too big, etc.

Comment: I have thought of that. That doesn't answer my question.